# Using a Grails service inside a script

Tags: grails, service, gant

I'm trying to use a Grails service inside the following Grails script

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(loadGames: "The description of the script goes here!") {
   def listFile = new File('list.txt')

   listFile.eachLine {
      def result = ctx.getBean("bggService").search(it)
      println it + " " + result.length()
   }
}

setDefaultTarget(loadGames)
```

I've seen about a dozen different webpages each offering a different combination of `ctx` `appCtx`, and `applicationContext` (as well as many others) as suggestions, however none of them work. Typically they complain that the context variable that I am trying to use does not exist.

Why can't Grails just use services inside a script in exactly the same way that they get used in controllers?

What is the right way to use a Grails service inside a Grails script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting hold of `ApplicationContext` and `grailsApplication` is possible though [`bootstrap`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/bootstrap.html) command. Include `_GrailsBootstrap` script, then call `configureApp ()` or depend on it in order to make `ApplicationContext` available in script:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")

target(loadGames: "The description of the script goes here!") {
   depends(configureApp)

   def listFile = new File('list.txt')

   listFile.eachLine {
      //Once configureApp() called ApplicationContext can be accessed as appCtx
      def result = appCtx.getBean("bggService").search(it)
      println it + " " + result.length()
   }
}

setDefaultTarget(loadGames)
```

Comment: What I don't understand about this answer, is how the script is being invoked.  If you are running the script from the **grails>** prompt (i.e. **grails>** loadGames) I would expect that you would have to include GrailsInit, and GrailsBootstrap (as you do in the example). It will balk when it hits the appCtx reference.  However, if you use the **run-script** command to do this, it balks when it hits the target statement. I can get simple scripts to work, but anything that involves calls to domain objects and services will fail.  This doesn't seem to work in 2.4.2.