# How can Services be be accessed within Grails scripts?

Tags: grails

The documentation on create-script/run-script is minimal so I'm wondering if it's possible to to inject/use domain classes in grails scripts. 
In a normal grails class I could inject a service like:

def myService

but I'm not sure where is would go inside of a grails script

Comment: question appears to be confusing ? I'm wondering if it's possible to to inject/use domain classes in grails scripts. is this the question or is it injecting a service into grails script which it ends with and is the subject of question?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/22977864/2051952

Answer (score 1):

To use domainClasses in scripts:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")
```

at the top

Then within function requiring access to add:

```
depends(bootstrap)

def myDomainClass = grailsApp.classLoader.loadClass("myapp.MyDomainClass")
def myDomainClassList = myDomainClass.list()
```

There is lots of information on all of this in The Definitive Guide to Grails 2

Comment: Would this work the same way with a service bean? I.E. Initialized by Spring.

Comment: @Vinny try `grailsApp.mainContext.getBean('serviceName')`

Comment: Thanks Sérgio Michels, that was what did it for me. Now put it in an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When using Grails 2.4.3, here is my complete solution:

First, as is mentioned in ["Error loading plugin manager: TomcatGrailsPlugin" on Grails 2.3 Database Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817539/error-loading-plugin-manager-tomcatgrailsplugin-on-grails-2-3-database-migrat) by Tai, change the tomcat build type in buildConfig.groovy to compile instead of build like so:

```
compile ':tomcat:7.0.42'
```

This avoids the “Error loading plugin manager: TomcatGrailsPlugin” error which would otherwise occur every time you run your script.

Next, create scripts/DoSomething.groovy

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClasspath")

target(main: "An example script that calls a service") {
    depends(bootstrap)

    def someService = appCtx.getBean("someService") // look up the service
    someService.runReportOrSomething() // invoke a method on the service
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

The above code causes the entire Grails stack to initialize, so all your services, domain classes, etc. will be set up for you.

Finally, to run it, do this:

```
grails prod do-something --stacktrace -echoOut
```

You might be tempted to do "grails run-script scripts/DoSomething.groovy but for whatever reason that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sounds good. Will mark as the answer when I can find some time to test this. Thanks!